# Removing a cloned repo

Tags: c#, git, ngit

I'd like to remove a cloned repo on disk using NGit, which is a port of JGit.

I've previously done this to clone a remote repo locally:

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(someDir);
var clone = Git.CloneRepository().SetDirectory(someDir).SetURI(someRepoUri);
Git Repo = clone.Call();
```

I'd like now to delete that local directory containing that cloned repo.

I was receiving permission exceptions when simply calling `System.IO.Directory.Delete()` when it reached the `.git\objects\pack\*.idx` files. Perhaps this is just a side effect of running this on Windows Azure.

Is there an NGit command I can issue to have the `.git` directory and all its contents removed by using functionality within NGit?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have any existing git/NGit process which you keep an handle on those resources (`.git\objects\pack\*.idx` files).

Not killing those processes is generally the reason for [those "`rm: cannot unlink ...`" error messages](http://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg130273.html).

Comment: Any suggestions on how to kill the relevant processes from code? I'm doing something similar to p.cambell in a unit test & need to delete the repo after successfully cloning it. I've tried [ var repository = _git.GetRepository(); repository.Close(); repository.ObjectDatabase.Close(); repository = null; ] before trying to delete the physical files, but still get the same message.